# angular app image not loading all folders from asset folder in the browser

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

[image]

So I have an angular app where I have asset folder and inside that I have few other folder. Surprisingly few folders load in browser, few does not. In the angular.json I have asset folder mention but still some folders did not load. to be specific mixing-box folder, industrial-silencer folder is loading but not other folders. Also in the Template I gave path as src='assets/images/product/......' and it throws 404 error on request

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/images/product/transition"
            ],
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change assets to something like below. It will copy all files/folders of assets to your dist folder

```
"assets": [
     "src/favicon.ico",
     {
          "glob": "**/*",
          "input": "src/assets",
          "output": "/assets/",
     }
],
```

Now, update image references to something like this

```
<img src="/assets/images/product/weather-hood/image.jpg" ...>
```

Image should load

Comment: Hi, The image folders are already in the dist folder but somehow it did not load in the browser. Still tried with your suggested changes also but no luck. Also if you see images weather-hood folder is loading. Transition, light-industrial-silencer etc are not loading in the browser

Comment: I dont think your script copies the whole assets folder. Notice that transition folder is missing. Are you to able to access these file? http://localhost:4200/assets/images/VAW-Logo-Website-white.png or http://localhost:4200/assets/images/product/transition/0.JPG If not the copy doesn't work. Check the dist folder if all the contents are there and copied correctly

Comment: I can access  localhost:4200/assets/images/VAW-Logo-Website-white.png  but not the transition folder images, Which is my issue, for which I have to post this question here. and I see all the contents in dist folder(all folders inside asset folder) but I am not sure why it does load in browser. and if I directly request the image by typing the URL of image it redirect to my home page.

Comment: VAW-Logo-Website-white.png loads because it is available in the dist folder and it indicates that you process is correct. The others are not loading bcos they are not accessible with the URL path you are using or build is not copying correctly. Check if the path is indeed correct. Run command `npm run build:dev`. And check what is in your `./dist` folder. It will give you clues what the correct path is